# jQuery sliding menu function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i have a unordered list menu, trying to make the sub-items slide down and up on clicking at the main items, i wrote a jQuery code that works but when click at open menu it close it and open again, but i was hoping it will just close it.

html

```
<div class="menuNav">
  <ul>
  <li><span>item_1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>sub-item_1-1</li>
      <li>sub-item_1-2</li>
      <li>sub-item_1-3</li>
      <li>sub-item_1-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><span>item_2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>sub-item_2-1</li>
      <li>sub-item_2-2</li>
      <li>sub-item_2-3</li>
      <li>sub-item_2-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><span>item_3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>sub-item_3-1</li>
      <li>sub-item_3-2</li>
      <li>sub-item_3-3</li>
      <li>sub-item_3-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.menuNav ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp("fast");
        $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass('menuactive');
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown("slow");
        $(this).addClass('menuactive');
        });

    $('.menuNav ul .menuactive').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp("fast");
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `li` has a class `menuactive`, call the `slideUp()` function and remove the class `menuactive` else call the `slideUp()` function on all `ul`s, remove the class `menuactive` from all `li`s, call `slideDown()` on the one that was clicked and add the class `menuactive` to the one that was clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul > li > ul').hide();
  $('.menuNav > ul > li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('menuactive')) {
      $(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast');
      $(this).removeClass('menuactive');
    } else {
      $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp('fast');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('menuactive');
      $(this).find('ul').slideDown('fast');
      $(this).addClass('menuactive');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menuactive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuNav">
  <ul>
    <li><span>item_1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>sub-item_1-1</li>
        <li>sub-item_1-2</li>
        <li>sub-item_1-3</li>
        <li>sub-item_1-4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><span>item_2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>sub-item_2-1</li>
        <li>sub-item_2-2</li>
        <li>sub-item_2-3</li>
        <li>sub-item_2-4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><span>item_3</span>
      <ul>
        <li>sub-item_3-1</li>
        <li>sub-item_3-2</li>
        <li>sub-item_3-3</li>
        <li>sub-item_3-4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: works just perfect, many you know what to do, thank u very match, would you please tell me how to add ease to the sliding so it looks more interesting ?

Comment: @NasserKamal - You could use the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/easing/) library for easing.

Comment: thanks sir i have include jquery.easing.js at my file i think i have to adjust the jQuery code you sent me to call the easing, which i have no idea how to do that, would you please adjusted ?